# Redirect print stream from other class method

Tags: perl, oop, logging

Say I have a Parent and a Child classes. **I can modify only Child class.**

Parent class has some `print`'s in it.

```perl
package Parent;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new
{
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {};
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}

sub sayHello{
    my $self = shift;
    print "Hello world\n";
}

sub sayBye{
    my $self = shift;
    print "Bye world\n";
}

1;
```

In my Child class I have a method to print content into log files.

```perl
package Child;

use strict;
use warnings;

use parent 'Parent';

sub new
{
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = $class->SUPER::new();
    return $self;
}

sub talk{
    my $self = shift;
    $self->sayHello;
    $self->sayBye;
}

sub talkToLog{
    my $self = shift;

    my $logName = 'file.log';

    $self->log($logName, $self->sayHello); # Here's my best (not working) try
    $self->log($logName, $self->sayBye);
}

sub log{
    my $self = shift;
    my $filename = shift;
    my $string = shift;
    open(my $fh, ">>", $filename) || die "Couldn't open file $filename: $!";
    print $fh $string;
    close $fh;
    return;
}

1;
```

**Question:** Is there some way to "catch" the stream of those prints from Child class and log that content using the `log` method?

---

Here is the pl file I'm using to try.

```pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Child;
my $child = Child->new;

$child->talk;
$child->talkToLog;
```

It prints this in console:

```
Hello world
Bye world
Hello world
Bye world
```

Comment: Please don't use `new Child`. You'll find `Child->new` has far fewer hard-to-debug corner cases.

Comment: Ok, good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need something like this:

```
sub talkToLog{
    my $self = shift;

    my $logName = 'file.log';
    my $output = '';

    open TOOUTPUT, '>', \$output or die "Can't open TOOUTPUT: $!";
    select TOOUTPUT;

    $self->sayHello;
    $self->log($logName, $output);

    $output = '';
    $self->sayBye;
    $self->log($logName, $output);

    select STDOUT;
}
```

Comment: This is working great. I just changed `'>'` to `'>>'` to append new data in the log file. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, based on ilux answer, I modified Child class adding two new methods to make the code cleaner: `buffer_start` and `buffer_get_clean`.

They are similar to PHP's `ob_start` and `ob_get_clean` methods, but you just have to add `buffer` attribute to the class (`$self->{buffer}`).

```
package Child;

use strict;
use warnings;

use parent 'Parent';

sub new
{
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = $class->SUPER::new();
    $self->{buffer} = '';    # <---- Note this
    return $self;
}

sub talk{
    my $self = shift;
    $self->sayHello;
    $self->sayBye;
}

sub talkToLog{
    my $self = shift;

    my $logName = 'file.log';

    # Cleaner way:

    $self->buffer_start;
    $self->sayHello;
    $self->log($logName, $self->buffer_get_clean);

    $self->buffer_start;
    $self->sayBye;
    $self->log($logName, $self->buffer_get_clean);
}

sub buffer_start{
    my $self = shift;
    open my $fh, '>>', \$self->{buffer};
    select $fh;
}

sub buffer_get_clean{
    my $self = shift;
    select STDOUT;
    my $buffer = $self->{buffer};
    $self->{buffer} = '';
    return $buffer;
}

sub log{
    my $self = shift;
    my $filename = shift;
    my $string = shift;
    open(my $fh, ">>", $filename) || die "Couldn't open file $filename: $!";
    print $fh $string;
    close $fh;
    return;
}

1;
```

Hope this helps!